# Zip File Streaming throws CRC Errors

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to read multiple files as BLOB (from database), decompress, zip them and stream the zipped file using JAX-WS. The above code streams the zip file but the downloaded zip file is not opened by windows program throwing CRC errors. After going through some posts, I added zipOutputStream.finish() (just before zipOutStream.flush()) which seemed to fix the error but zips only one file and ignores other files.

Any help is much appreciated

```
try (ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        try (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteStream)) {

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Blob blob = getBlob();

                try (InputStream fileInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream())) {
                    try (ByteArrayOutputStream fileByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                        //  Custom method: Copy the above fileInputStream to fileByteStream
                        IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, fileByteStream);
                        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);                    
                        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
                            zipOutputStream.write(fileInputStream.toByteArray());
                        zipOutputStream.flush();
                        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                    }
                }

                try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream.toByteArray());) {
                    InputStreamDataSource inputDataSource = new InputStreamDataSource(fileName, inputStream);
                    dataHandler = new DataHandler(inputDataSource);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such method as `InputStream.toByteArray()`. Post the real code.

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the code. its fileByteStream.toByteArray()